# Python error - TypeError: create_or_update() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python, azure, azureportal

I am new to Python and I am trying to create firewall rules on the azure portal. However I am getting the following error `TypeError: create_or_update() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given`

This is my python script thus far:

```
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.sql import SqlManagementClient

GROUP_NAME = 'xxxxxxxxx'
SERVER_NAME = 'xxxxxxxxx'
SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'xxxxxxxxx'

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(
    exclude_interactive_browser_credential=False)

client = ResourceManagementClient(
       credential=credential,
       subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

for resource_group in client.resource_groups.list():
    print(f"Resource group: {resource_group.name}")

print(f"Successful credential: {credential._successful_credential.__class__.__name__}")

client = SqlManagementClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

print("Add firewall rule")
# Open access to this server for IPs
firewall_rule = client.firewall_rules.create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME,
    SERVER_NAME,
    "test_rule",
    "123.123.123.123",
    "123.123.123.123"
    )
```

[image]

Comment: `create_or_update` is a method, which implies `self` is the first argument. Try removing the last argument and send "only 4".

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're running? On the basis of what you've shown (after you edited it) there are undoubtedly 5 parameters being passed

Comment: Is self defined as client.firewall_rules?
`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: @DarkKnight as you can see from the command prompt I am running in a virtual environment which contains the script authentication.py and I am running `python authentication.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `create_or_update` definition [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-sql/azure.mgmt.sql.operations.firewallrulesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--server-name--firewall-rule-name--parameters----kwargs-),

```
create_or_update(resource_group_name, server_name, firewall_rule_name, parameters, **kwargs)
```

You will notice that the `parameters` is of [`FirewallRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-sql/azure.mgmt.sql.models.firewallrule?view=azure-python) type. Can you try to create an object of this type and use it in your method? Something like:

```
firewallRule = FirewallRule(name="Something", start_ip_address="123.123.123.123", end_ip_address="123.123.123.123")
firewall_rule = client.firewall_rules.create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME,
    SERVER_NAME,
    "test_rule",
    firewallRule
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing that definition.
I had to add `from azure.mgmt.sql.models import FirewallRule` to my script too but now its working!!